# Disable gdb output for a specific command

Tags: gdb

I want to run the following commands in gdb:

```
while 1
x $pc
stepi
end
```

But I don't want the output of stepi command. Is there a way to disable only stepi command output?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try out [gdbpython](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Basic-Python.html):

```
while True:
    gdb.execute("x/i $pc") # you can see the output on terminal
    gdb.execute("stepi", to_string=True) # so that you cannot see its output
    # some stop criteria here?
```

type to the gdb like this:

```
python
while True:
    gdb.execute("x/i $pc")
    gdb.execute("stepi", to_string=True)
end
```